# Adding picture, what is framing?

Tags: bug, status-reproduced, editing, suggested-edits

In order to improve [this post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/47141/name-of-experiment), I was trying to add [this picture](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-KCN0vmahqCw/UZq0xvR6D4I/AAAAAAAAAe4/KKYHhD2jwEY/w800-h800/INKrGUS.gif)(it doesn't load here either) to it ; but what I get is:"For security reasons, framing is not allowed; click OK to remove the frames." And then I'm redirected to another page with a big *Oops* in it.

What does this mean? I thought it might be because of the descriptions below the photo, so I removed them and tried again, without any success. Can anyone help me with this regard?

**Update:**

I will upload some pictures of the sequence of what happens:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Ah, I see what's going on now that you've posted screenshots. The framing issue has nothing to do with the image you're uploading - you should be able to reproduce the same issue with other images. It seems to be a bug in the Stack Exchange image uploader. Accordingly I've deleted my answer.

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky but you said you were able to upload the photo.

Comment: Though I will leave a mention that it's not appropriate to include that image in a Physics SE post unless you can verify that it is available under a Creative Commons-compatible license.

Comment: (2 comments up) yeah, that's how bugs are. They're very sensitive to the details of your computer setup. In this case it probably has something to do with which web browser you're using, so if you could edit details about your operating system (Ubuntu?) and web browser, including version numbers, into the question, that would help a lot.

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky I'm not sure how to do so, apparently the photo is from a contest held by NewScientist. How does one generally verify if such licenses exist?

Comment: I did some tests, there is clearly something fishy going on here. Normal images upload fine. That image doesn't.

Comment: @Manishearth (or Ali) did you try another animated GIF of comparable file size?

Comment: Just a note: repro'd on Chrome stable on Ubuntu 13.04.

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky I'm trying

Comment: Same here: Chromium browser; Version 28.0.1500.52 Ubuntu 13.04 (28.0.1500.52-0ubuntu1.13.04.3)

Comment: Other gifs work. I'm going to try pulling something off SSL.

Comment: @Ali Note: Chromium is not one of the supported browsers here. Note sure about Chrome Linux.

Comment: @Ali (8 comments up) Usually the web page you download the image from will state the license it is available under. Failing that, you could contact the copyright holder (probably New Scientist, but might be the person who created the image) and ask if they are willing to release it under a CC license, but in practice the chances of getting an affirmative answer are not good. If you don't see an explicit statement of the license, it is "all rights reserved" which means you can't upload it to SE.

Comment: OK, tried it with a normal GIF, an animated GIF, a normal image on SSL, an animated GIF on SSL. Both uploading from computer and using the link. All work fine.

Comment: To compare, the SSL animated gif I used was [this one](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/35/Nuclear_Force_anim_smaller.gif) (my own creation)

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky Thanks for your guide, I'll check that. Manishearth I didn't know chromium was not one of the supported browsers, how were I supposed to know so? :) But everything has worked properly so far(instead of this tiny mischievous bug)

Comment: @Manishearth when you say SSL or non-SSL, you mean accessing Stack Exchange via (non-)SSL, right? Also I have managed to reproduce this using the same version of Chromium on Gentoo.

Comment: @Ali "supported" means very little in practice, only that if there is a bug, SE will want it reproduced on a supported browser before they try to fix it.

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky Yep. SE via SSL is just a 301 redirect, though it's partially live on dev.* afaict. However, they're slowly getting stuff into place for SSL. One of these things was shifting part of the image system CloudFlare (done 2 days ago iirc). Nick had mentioned that there may be issues with this, and to ping him if this was the case. (already pinged)

Comment: @Ali It will work on unsupported browsers, but they may not fix specific bugs that only appear on these browsers. Irrelevant here, I use Chrome.

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need

Comment: I've also reproduced it (at least I think it's the same bug) on Firefox 22. P.S. @Manishearth what is this dev.*, did you become an SE developer without telling us? :-P

Comment: Also about the license, it is stated [here](http://www.newscientist.com/info/in216?full=true):"Academic use

Academic organisations may reproduce our content free of charge provided New Scientist is clearly credited as the source. No permission is required for this." I think this means that I am allowed to upload the photo.

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky Maaaaybe.... I may have gone the way of the Sklivvz :P No, I'm definitely not a dev, I just know that https://dev.stackoverflow.com/ and https://dev.meta.stackoverflow.com/ exist. And are currently (partially?) running https.

Comment: @Ali No, it doesn't. If you'd like to take this to [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71/the-h-bar) I can explain why.

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky sure, I'm all ears!

Answer (score 2):

Apparently it throws this exception on large animated GIFs. I took a screencap of a certain anime I'm watching and converted it to a GIF [here](http://manishearth.anapnea.net/anim.gif). It's over 7 megabytes and gives the same error.

Chrome Stable on Ubuntu 13.04

---

For the record, this exception comes from a [frame buster](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Framekiller) used to prevent [clickjacking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clickjacking), [CSRF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery), and the like. Basically, it prevents you from putting an SE site within an HTML frame on a different domain.

The image uploader does indeed use iframes, the response is delivered in a same-domain iframe which then calls a callback function in the parent frame<sup>1</sup>. However, being same-domain, that error should not get thrown.

I assume that the large image is breaking something, causing the inner page to seem to load on a different domain (abut:blank maybe, that's what it looks like)

<sup>1. I'm not entirely sure why they haven't used a simple POST request here, but they probably have their reasons.</sup>

Comment: Is the footnote aiming at me?

Comment: @Ali No, by "they" I mean "developers". A few months back I had been trying to reverse-engineer the image upload for a userscript I was writing, and I discovered that they used framing to make it work. I don't see why it can't be done without framing, that's all. Again, they probably have good reasons.